# Get value from txt file and change random wise on every reload in PHP

Tags: php

I have 1000+ values in txt file (separated by commas). I need to change the value everytime page get reload or for every new visitor.

I mention a piece of code below, hope you got it. Please help me - how can I get the value from txt file and randomly change it for every visitor?
I have value in root directory named: **"values.txt"**

```
<iframe src="https://example.com/results.html?t={VALUES}" width="336" height="280" 
        frameborder="0" scrolling="no"allowautotransparency=true>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_rand_values()
{
$file = file_get_contents("values.txt");
$file = explode(",",$file);
return $file[rand(0,count($file)-1)];
}
```

Comment: sorry, i tried but its not working mate, please double check. appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you provide an error message or more context why this is not working? For me it looks perfectly fine.

Comment: this answer came in Low Quality posts in SO.... Could you add any commentary to your answer? Explain your logic, and give a little commentary on what your code is intended to do. This will help the OP, but it will also serve as commentary for future users